# Change the package of generated supporting files in Swagger codegen

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger-codegen

While generating the server stub, in my case spring type, I can specify the packages for `api`, `model` and `invoker`. And it works without problems.

I need also change the package for generated supporting files. I'm not able to find the way how to do that. The default package is `io.swagger.configuration` which needs to be changed in my case.

Answer (score 3):

The Swagger-Codegen support the option when generate code. The detail you can check the official wiki section [customizing-the-generator](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen#customizing-the-generator)

Let me make an example by using generation to jersey2

```
java -jar ${your_swagger_codegen_jar} generate \
    -i ${your_api_url} \
    -l java --library=jersey2 \
    -o ${your_output_folder} \
    -c ./config.json
```

The config.json

```
{
  "hideGenerationTimestamp":true,
  "groupId":"science.mengxin",
  "artifactId":"test-api-client",
  "artifactDescription":"test-api-client",
  "developerName":"xin.meng",
  "developerEmail":"test@test.com",
  "developerOrganization":"mengxin",
  "developerOrganizationUrl":"mengxin.science",
  "licenseName":"mengxin.science",
  "invokerPackage":"science.mengxin.test.cloud.client",
  "apiPackage":"science.mengxin.test.cloud.client.api",
  "modelPackage":"science.mengxin.test.cloud.client.model"
}
```

Then check `pom.xml` and source code of generated code, you will find all these parameters has been customised.

The more options to customise the generated code can be found in the swagger-codegen book: [English](https://gumroad.com/l/swagger_codegen_beginner), [Chinese](https://gumroad.com/l/swagger_codegen_beginner_zh)

Comment: As I wrote, I can specify the packages for `api`, `model` and `invoker`. And that's the same you can achieve using your jason configuration. The problem is that he package for supporting files cannot be changed, it's a separate group to the three listed above. I'm talking about directories like: `.swagger-codegen` and `.swagger-codegen-ignore`. They will always be generated in the "native" form even if you tell Swagger to use custom `.swagger-codegen-ignore` (the "regular" one will always be generated in a "regular" location).

Comment: The ultimate flexible usage of swagger-codegen is template customize by using `-t <template directory>, --template-dir <template directory> folder containing the template files`. The default template can be found in the source code `modules/swaggercodegen/src/main/resources`. However, for `.swagger-codegen-ignore` will be skipped after you add some code in it because the swagger-codegen will skip all files defined in this file. I think swagger-codegen do not support change folder for this files and `.swagger-codegen` folder. Why do you want to change the folder for them?